# How do I install Battlefield 3 on Origin without Downloading it?

Tags: battlefield-3, origin

It might sound weird.

I have the main Data files in a folder `cas_06.cas` etc etc.

(I have all the files. The Data ones are the biggest (GBs) And would save the most time)

I have tried placing them where they are to be downloaded to. But it doesn't seem to want to use/update these files.

Is there anyway to `verify cache` as you could in Steam, for it to check current contents and what else is needed?

Or any other way for it to accept these files on my PC without re-downloading them. Thanks

Comment: add tag of battlefield-3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to traffic restrictions at my dorm I had to install my Battlefield 3 like this:

- Install Origin & Download Battlefield 3 at a friends home to my netbook
- copy the entire folder for battlefield 3 from there to my own origin installation at my home pc
- Start Origin and start the installation of Battlefield 3

Origin then looked if it already had the files in its Folder and skipped the download for every file. So it looked like it was downloading but it wasn't (it only checked the files).

After a minute or so, the game was installed properly and I could play normally.

Comment: Thanks. It kept saying error for me though. And wipeing out all the files. Even when I downloaded about 6GB properly. In the end I re-downloaded another 15GB. such a headache :/

Answer (score 1):

Its a little complicated compared to installing other games. You have to be online to validate or create your origin ID and then you can install the game offline. I downloaded an update of Origin from my phone an pasted into the Origin Program Files folder, then exit Origin and install the game from setup.exe file in the disk and follow the prompts.

If it says downloading, just make sure it's loading from disk not Internet, I did this by disconnecting my internet. It will show download progress until it reaches 100% from disk in the games thumbnail under the games tab in Origin. If this works it will ask for 2nd disk at 50%.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone looks at this question looking for an answer:

Don't copy all the files, just click "Download" and be ready to pause the download when a large file has a copy of itself with "STREAM" at the end of the name (I'm not quite sure if it's in the extension or the name).

When you see the file, pause the download. Delete the file without STREAM on its name and paste the one you already had in the backup. Then continue the download and it should skip that file as it's already complete. Repeat for every STREAM file you see.

That's how I installed BF4 after a fresh OS installation.